# Error installing package mapclassify in Python

Tags: python, maps, installation

I received a notebook, that contains the code below:

`(...)
import mapclassify.api as mc
(...)`

I tried to run and received the error message: "No module named 'mapclassify' "

So, I installed mapclassify package, with the code: `$ pip install mapclassify`

But now, the error message is: "No module named 'mapclassify.api' "

What I have to do?

Comment: In this page https://github.com/ljwolf/mapclassify/blob/master/README.md the autor also used `mapclassify.api`

Comment: That is a fork of the original repo and has not been updated since last year. It therefor reflects an outdated version of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api` was removed from `mapclassify` starting with version 2.0.

From the [github](https://github.com/pysal/mapclassify/tree/master/mapclassify), this was the syntax in [1.0.1](https://github.com/pysal/mapclassify/tree/v1.0.1):

```
>>> import mapclassify.api as mc
>>> y = mc.load_example()
>>> y.mean()
125.92810344827588
>>> y.min(), y.max()
(0.13, 4111.4499999999998)
```

and became this with [2.0.0](https://github.com/pysal/mapclassify/tree/v2.0.0):

```
>>> import mapclassify
>>> y = mapclassify.load_example()
>>> y.mean()
125.92810344827588
>>> y.min(), y.max()
(0.13, 4111.4499999999998)
```